# How to get a key from an array in anonymous function?

Tags: php, anonymous-function

How can I get a key from an array in anonymous function , using 'array_map' ?

```
    array_map(function($v) {
        echo $v.'<br/>'; //get key (container..e.t.c)
    },array(
        'CONTAINER' => $this->CONTAINER ,
        'CONTAINER_USE_KEY' => $this->CONTAINER_USE_KEY ,
        'LINE' => $this->LINE
    ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use `array_walk()` instead of `array_map()` you can do this:

```
$data = array(
    'CONTAINER' => $this->CONTAINER ,
    'CONTAINER_USE_KEY' => $this->CONTAINER_USE_KEY ,
    'LINE' => $this->LINE
);

array_walk($data, function($value, $key) {
    echo $key . '<br/>';
});
```